# Need to getElementById twice to get correct value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am setting a scrollTop animation to keep a chat view displaying the latest message at the bottom.

I fire the following method as follows when loading the conversation and after sending a message:

```
loadMessages(matchId) {
    ...
    // ..filling the messages array..
    this.scrollToBottom();
    ...
}

sendMessage(matchId) {
    ...
    // ..updating the messages array..
    this.scrollToBottom();
    ...
}

scrollToBottom() {
    const div = document.getElementById('contentArea');
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
}
```

chat.css:

```
.contentArea {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.267);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I need to click on `loadMessages()` twice to get the scroll to happen, same thing when a send a message, I need to send two messages to get the content scroll to the first of the two messages..

It looks like I have to `document.getElementById('contentArea')` twice to get the correct value..

I guess I am calling the function too soon to get the correct value the first time.

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Need more code to figure out what's wrong, there is nothing wrong in the code you posted, so the problem might be in the code you didnt post

Comment: I don't really know what else to add as there is not so much to it... I added some css. What else would you need? I am working in an Angular component if it could help

Comment: @AvcS Looks like `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` need two calls to be calculated

Comment: stackblitz with a MVCE that replicates the issue would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that you are manipulating DOM and trying to read the updated DOM values immediately.

Changes applied to the DOM elements are not applied immediately, all the changes made to the DOM in a single execution cycle are collected and applied in one repaint.

So you need to wait for the repaint to complete before trying to read the updated dimensions of the element.

`requestAnimationFrame` is a method that is executed before every repaint, you can use it to calculate the `scrollHeight` before next repaint, i.e it will be called after current repaint and you will get the correct `scrollHeight` value

```
scrollToBottom() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        const div = document.getElementById('contentArea');
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
    });
}
```

> **PS:** This solution is based on the assumption that you are calling `scrollToBottom` method directly after a DOM manipulation, I am not sure if that is what is happening because you didn't share the code surrounding your `scrollToBottom` call. But based on your method names and comments I guess this is the reason for your issue.